# Capturing parameters appended to the DWR3 query string?

Tags: javascript, html, json, servlets, dwr

I have a method called `myMethod` which maps to the following DWR method:

```
List<MyObject> myMethod(String param){
...
return myObjects
}
```

A library calls this method automatically by referring to `MyService.myMethod('value')`, but it also appends its own params, `a`, and `b`

That is, the final request looks like this:

**POST**
http://localhost:8080/application/dwr/jsonp/MyService/myMethod/value?a=5&b=6

Is there any way to capture the values of `a` and `b` easily through DWR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get at the HttpServletRequest.

```
WebContext ctx = WebContextFactory.get();
ctx.getHttpServletRequest().getParam(...)
```